# Firebug HTML/CSS not visible as it's covered by grey block

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

I am not able to view HTML/CSS within the HTML panel.It is covered by some grey block. I reinstalled Firefox and Firebug but the issue still persists. Can anyone guide me how I can remove this grey block?

Comment: Please use the [Firebug issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/list) to report problems with that add-on.

Comment: @user3724751 Did my answer solve your problem? You should post some screenshot (or a link to one), so people can see what you mean. And you should also provide the version of Firefox and Firebug you used to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in the [FAQ to Firebug](https://getfirebug.com/faq#Why_does_resizing_the_Firebug_frame_display_a_gray_block) this is not a bug in Firebug, but known to be caused by the following extensions:

- [Lazarus: Form Recovery 2.3](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/lazarus-form-recovery/) ([seems to be fixed](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=5649#c3) in [version 3.2](http://getlazarus.com/download))
- [Pentadactyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/)
- [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/)